# Multi-apartment remodel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I am working on remodeling an old meeting house into eight individual micro-apartments. The City has been unable to identify the load that will be needed, and I am trying to figure out the NEC calculations for multi-unit service. But, I would like someone to check my numbers...

Each apartment is approximately 450 sq ft (450 * 3vA = 1350vA), plus the presumed two small appliances (3000vA). Additionally, each will have its own mini-split A/C & heat system (15A x 240v = 3600vA), but there will be a communal washer/dryer area, comprised of two stacked units. Each unit will also have it's own stove range (40A x 240v = 9600vA). I was also going to use tankless water heaters, 18kW units using 75A (18000vA), but if that's going to be my big user, then I may switch to 30gal tanks, 3.8 kW (3800vA).

As I understand the table, for the general load, the first 3000vA gets calculated at 100%, with the remaining 1350vA at 35% (3000 + 473). The A/C unit and range are at 100% (3600vA + 9600vA) and the water heater at 75% (18000 x .75 = 13500vA or 3800 x .75 = 2850vA). For sake of further calculations, I'll use the tanked water heater.

That brings me to 19,523vA per unit (3000+473+3600+9600+2850). Multiplied by 8, that's 156,184vA demand. Throw in another 10,000vA for the two communal dryers, and that brings the total to 166,184vA demand. The formula I found is Demand=vA/(240 x 1.732) for single phase service... So 400 amp service required (which is significantly lower than I was imagining, so I may have gotten lost in the numbers).

In addition to not being ablet to figure out what is needed to supply the demand, the building currently has 3-phase power coming into it, but the City says that will only supply a single 200 amp panel (which doesn't make sense to me, either). I would have thought that the 3-phase power line would have supplied more than that, possibly even enough for the apartments all together.

The local municipality is the electric supplier (I just referred to them as the City). I don't want to refer to anyone specifically by name.

The common area consists only of an exterior hallway running between the apartments. It is a total of 400 sq ft (80 ft long x 5 ft wide).

I'm open to a common meter, and then I would install individual meters inside the building to monitor usage. If I have the City put in the meter boxes, they will charge me for those anyway, so I may as well individually meter the units.

Am I totally off with my load calculation?

Comment: What city - the city is the electric utility? If not, what electric utility?

Comment: Yes, who is your electric utility?

Comment: Also, how many square feet is the commons area?

Comment: ...and I think you remembered the 2 20A circuits for each kitchen, but forgot the 20A circuit for each bathroom. Hmm - you computed those as 15A?

Comment: You haven't explicitly stated it, but the math suggests these 8 units will be common-metered rather than each having their own meter?

Comment: @Ecnerwal -- the NEC Art 220 calculation treats bathroom circuits as part of the general lighting load

Comment: If single phase 240/120v then 166,184VA / 240v = 692A .

Comment: You now seem to have created 2 accounts, as you should be able to edit your own question without having it go through the review queue. Please [click here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for instructions on merging them.

Comment: Additionally, the folks here seem to be pretty good at ferreting out the exact code documents for random locale's around the US and other places in the world. By providing the city/utility name, someone may be able to find the _exact_ documents you need to calculate exactly what the city will off you and require of you for this project. Unless it's a city of two people, there are going to be a lot of "Franks" in town, so nobody will be able to identify you from just a utility company name.

Comment: If the units will be separately metered (by the utility, not privately sub-metered by you) then you have 9 independent load calculations: one for each unit and one for the commons area. It appears each will come in well under 100 amps and you could buy a crate of 100 A (or larger) meter/main panels of a type accepted by the utility. It'll be the utility's problem to work out how to feed all those, total kVA, whether you're paying them to install a transformer, etc.

Comment: I would have thought this wasn't about home improvement.

Comment: If this is in the United States and you are the owner or landlord of this apartment complex, then you cannot do any of this work yourself even if you are a licensed electrician, just FYI.

Comment: @GregHill -- utilities have a habit of fobbing metering hardware off onto the customer these days (which has its advantages)

Comment: My comment would be tankless water heaters for 8 units, are you nuts? , how can your total be 19.5kw when the tankless units are 18 by themselves. , just checking on your 3 phase I would expect it to be 120/208 today not 120/240

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because wiring an 8-unit apartment doesn't fall under _Home_ Improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Three-phase changes the load calculation calculus

The first, and most sweeping, issue with your calculations is that you are assuming that you are getting a 240VAC three-phase service from the utility, which is atypical, especially for a building that is having its service entrance reworked.  This is because a 240V three phase service will be a *delta* service, either an unbalanced high leg (wild leg, stinger leg, power leg) delta that provides 120V at the cost of phase balance, or a *corner grounded* delta that provides a balanced 240V three phase source but no 120V.  If you *do* have a delta service, and the power company is not willing to change you over to a balanced wye service, then post a comment here and I'll re-evaluate your options based on what kind of delta it is.

More normally, though, a "stock" utility three phase service will be a 208V *wye* service, that provides balanced supply and 120V at the cost of using 208V as the "high" voltage instead of 240V (blame phase angles).  As a result, we need to adjust several figures in the load calculations to match.  This also means that the water heaters need to be ordered as 208V units in order to get correct rated power; 240V heaters will function on a 208V supply, but they will only deliver 75% of their rated power, reducing their first hour recovery accordingly.

There's also the issue that you need to use the actual current draw of the minisplits instead of the circuit breaker rating.  For this calculation, I used the LG LS120HEV2 as a representative unit: it's a 1-ton (12kBTU), 20 SEER mini-split heatpump that supports operation on 208V in addition to 230V, pulling a maximum of 10A (its nameplate Minimum Circuit Ampacity).  Note that the choice of a 1-ton unit assumes that the building does not conform to modern energy codes; if it's being deep energy retrofitted, then it's possible to use smaller heatpumps yet.

### Now that that's out of the way...

With that out of the way, we can address the load calculations, starting with the individual studio units.  These start with 3kVA for their two small appliance circuits, then add 473VA for the demand factored (35%) lighting load (3VA/ft²). Moving onto the remaining (non-factored) loads, we have 8320VA (40A @ 208VAC, and slightly over the 8kVA required to support a 12kVA range) for the range load, 3800VA (as per your figures, this will change with what water heater you get) for a tank type hot water heater (tankless would close to double the per-unit wattage budget, requiring 200A feeds instead of 100 or 125A, and you'd need to get 208V specific units), and 2600VA (10A * 208V * 1.25 for the largest motor load on the feeder) for the mini-split, yielding a load of 18193VA, or 87A @ 208VAC.

We then move onto the commons area, which also has two small appliance (laundry) branch circuits that represent the washer loads at 1500VA a piece (since I don't know what washer you're getting), as well as 420VA of general lighting and receptacle load (this is computed using dwelling unit rules, which is bending things slightly, but in a conservative direction as corridors only require ½VA/ft² for lighting), 10kVA for the two domestic-type clothes dryers (at 5kVA a piece), another 3.8KVA for the water heater feeding the washers, and another 2.6kVA for HVAC for commons spaces, although that last load sounds like it may not be necessary.  This yields a conservative commons area load figure of 19820VA, or 95A @ 208VAC, assuming that the commons area is receiving a single phase feeder.

We then have to do a *recursive* load calculation for the overall service load, as various demand factors in the Code apply when you have multiples of the same type of appliance on the same service, resulting in a simple sum severely overestimating the ampacity required.  We start with the 3kVA from the commons area "SABCs" for the washers, and then move onto the two factored load sources: the 8400VA of factored SABC load from the studio kitchens, and the 4200VA of factored lighting load from the 4000ft² overall of building present.  With those sources out of the way, we then tackle the non-factored loads, starting with the 23kVA for the 8 ranges of 12kVA or less from table 220.55, then moving onto the 9 HVAC units and their 19240VA of load, and the 10kVA from the two clothes dryers.  Finally, we multiply the combined water heater load by 75% due to the load demand factor for 4 or more appliances of the same type found in NEC 220.53, yielding 25.65kVA of water heating load.  Totaling this up yields 93.49kVA, which is then divided by 208V, then divided again by √3 since we are presuming the service is a three phase wye, yielding a total of 260A of load, assuming even phase balance.

### As to the hardware needed

Generally speaking, multifamily buildings of this size are individually metered, using what's known as *modular metering* hardware.  (Master metering is frowned upon by electric utilities in this day and age for energy conservation reasons, and landlord-controlled submetering can run afoul of tenant-protection laws, while there's nowhere I know of that prohibits a multifamily dwelling from being individually revenue metered by the power company.)  While all of the major service equipment manufacturers make suitable hardware for this task, I'm partial to Siemens gear here as it's relatively inexpensive for what it does, is designed to be simple to install, and offers a comprehensive enough set of modules and approvals to handle most applications.

This brings us to what your utility requires for metering hardware.  There are two main styles of meter socket in use in the US: *ring-type* hardware that uses a sealing ring to hold the meter in the socket, and *ringless* hardware that uses a locked or tamper-sealed cover to hold the meter in place.  Furthermore, many utilities require the common area circuits in a multifamily building to be equipped with an appropriate *bypass* so they can service the meter without cutting power to key building functions -- ringless meters generally use a lever bypass, while ring-style meters that have a bypass function always use a *test block bypass* ("safety socket").  We also have to take *fault currents* into consideration; outside of downtowns (and much of NYC), you won't often run into a short-circuit current higher than 65kA at the service point, but we still need to account for it as utilities generally don't guarantee a maximum fault current for commercial or multifamily services.

With all this said, we move into the actual hardware necessary.  If your utility uses ringless hardware, as is typical for utilities east of the Continental Divide, you need:

- A WB3400C for the service entrance module (if space is tight, you can use the T variation for an overhead service or the B version for an underground service, instead)
- A pair of WMM42125RJ ringless meter stack modules for the feeds to the individual units
- A WML12225RJ ringless lever bypass meter stack module for the common area
- And a WSPD3N for the service surge protector

If your utility is an EUSERC utility (the primary users of ring-style metering, generally found west of the Rockies), then you'll need to instead use a WEB3400B for the service entrance, a pair of WMM42125J ring-style meter stack modules for the unit feeds, and a WMT12225J for the common area feeder.

Either way, the rest of the service setup is the same.  You'll need 8 Q2100H breakers for the feeders to the units, and a Q2100H or QS2100 for the common area feeder.  The incoming service will be a 350 kcmil or 500 kcmil aluminum quadruplex cable in 3.5" PVC if it comes in underground or use 4 individual 500kcmil Al wires in a 4" RMC mast if brought to the building as an overhead service drop. With this, you'll need to run a 2AWG copper grounding electrode conductor (with clamp fitting) from the metering equipment into the building where it can connect to metal water mains or piping, as well as a 6AWG grounding electrode conductor from the metering equipment to the building grounding rods.

### Beyond the service equipment

For the various unit subpanels, you have two options:

- A *fully-rated* system, with all of the subpanel breakers rated for 22kA of fault current, but a minimum of 15' of 2AWG or 20' of 1AWG SER feeder cable required for each feeder to limit short circuit currents down to values the subpanel breakers can handle.  This means you have more flexibility (QO, Siemens, GE) in subpanel and branch breaker selection, at the cost of that minimum-distance limitation, having to use costlier branch breakers, and the inability to use some breakers (such as double-stuff/tandem breakers).
- A *series-rated* system, where the upstream breakers have to "help" the branch breakers with fault currents.  This limits you to Siemens panels and breakers for the subpanels since we're using Siemens metering hardware here, but means you can use the normal (10kA short circuit rating) Siemens breakers in the subpanels, and also means you don't have minimum cable lengths on the feeders to worry about.

Either way, you'll be wanting 24-space (or more), 125A, main lug panels for the various subpanels involved, with 2-2-2-4 Al SER cables for the feeders to the units and a 1-1-1-3 Al SER cable for the common area feeder.  If you wish to use a 125A feed to the common area subpanel, you can, but that requires a Q2125H or QS2125 feeder breaker and a 1/0-1/0-1/0-2 Al SER cable instead.

Comment: Thank you, ThreePhaseEel. I will carefully review everything you have said and discuss more with the city utility manager.